# How to surround every call to a dynamic object with a using statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to surround every call to a dynamic object with a using statement. For example I have a class that exposes a dynamic object, other classes call methods from that dynamic object.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public dynamic DynamicObject;
}

class SecondExampleClass
{
    exampleClassInstance.DynamicObject.SomeMethod();
}
```

I want to be able to surround all the calls to the dynamic object with a using statement:

```
class SecondExampleClass
{
    using (...) {
        exampleClassInstance.DynamicObject.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this automatically inside the wrapper class without having to explicitly add a using statement around every single call to the DynamicObject?

Comment: Where you refer to `DynamicObject` I assume you meant to write `exampleClassInstance.DynamicObject`?

Comment: Yes yes, sorry about the ambiguity :)

Comment: theres ways if you adjust the il

Comment: Maybe you could create a wrapper object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That works! Thanks!